# Pattern substitution in perl

Tags: perl

I would like to replace below line(string1) with string 2. Any idea how should I do it in perl?

```
$string1=project/Import/files/mymux.v
```

replace with => `project/micro/target_lib/MYMUX/functional/verilog.v`

In a replace string, micro,target_lib,verilog and functional are constant things. I just need to break,mymux.v into MYMUX and verilog.v. Any help would be appreciated!

Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: $string1=~s/Import\/files/micro\/target_lib/

Comment: I don't have any idea, how can I split, mymux.v into MYMUX and verilog.v

Answer (score 3):

```
my ($n) = $string1 =~ m{/([^/]+)\.v\z}
   or die;

my $string2 = 'project/micro/target_lib/'.uc($n).'/functional/verilog.v';
```

Comment: Thanks ikegami for prompt answer.

Comment: One issue here would be, .v extention is not a constant and it can be .sv sometimes, so I am trying to break verilog.v into two parts, verilog and .v so that code would work with any extention.